# Pandas: Create new column in DataFrame based on other column in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame called df that has the following data:

```
Index    SourceDate
0        AUG_2013
1        SEP_2013
2        JAN_2012
```

I need to add an additional column that turns each of these dates into the following ConvertedDate Column.  This column will have the date in YYYY-MM-DD format with the day always being 01.

```
Index    SourceDate    ConvertedDate
0        AUG_2013      2013-08-01
1        SEP_2013      2013-09-01
2        JAN_2012      2012-01-01
```

I attempted doing this with:

```
df['ConvertedDate'] = time.strptime(str.replace(str.rsplit(df.SourceDate,'_',1)[0],'_','-01-'),'%b-%d-%Y')
```

Unfortunately this does not work since df.SourceDate is a Series, and string functions won't work on a Series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html#pandas.to_datetime) and pass a format string:

```
In [64]:
df['ConvertedDate'] =pd.to_datetime(df['SourceDate'], format='%b_%Y')
df

Out[64]:
   Index SourceDate ConvertedDate
0      0   AUG_2013    2013-08-01
1      1   SEP_2013    2013-09-01
2      2   JAN_2012    2012-01-01
```

The python datetime format string specifiers can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)